# Why I am getting error as operation not permitted for copying files from one folder to another folder using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, path, copy, fs

I am trying to copy all the files from a folder to destination folder. I have also imported the **fs** and **path** package inside the code. Also I have removed the read-only option tick from properties of the foler and its files respectively. But still getting the below last error. How could I resolve this error?
This is my code:

```
 function sync(source, destination) {
    var files = [];

       //var targetFolder = path.join( destination, path.basename( source ) );
       var targetFolder = destination;
       if ( !fs.existsSync( targetFolder ) ) {
           fs.mkdirSync( targetFolder );
       }

       // Copy
       if ( fs.lstatSync( source ).isDirectory() ) {
           files = fs.readdirSync( source );
           files.forEach( function ( file ) {
               var curSource = path.join( source, file );

               if ( fs.lstatSync( curSource ).isDirectory() ) {
                   fs.copyFolderRecursiveSync( curSource, targetFolder );
               } else {
                   fs.copyFileSync( curSource, targetFolder );
               }
           });
       }
  };
```

This is how I passing the source and the destination parameters:

```
  sync('D:/New folder', 'D:/New folder (2)');
```

But I am getting this error:

```
calling
internal/fs/utils.js:307
    throw err;
    ^

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, copyfile 'D:\New folder\New Text Document (1).txt' -> 'D:/New folder (2)'
    at Object.copyFileSync (fs.js:1991:3)
    at C:\Users\em\Desktop\influence\memecache.js:171:23
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at sync (C:\Users\em\Desktop\influence\memecache.js:165:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\em\Desktop\influence\memecache.js:151:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12) {
  errno: -4048,
  syscall: 'copyfile',
  code: 'EPERM',
  path: 'D:\\New folder\\New Text Document (1).txt',
  dest: 'D:/New folder (2)'
}
```

Answer (score -1):

fs.copyFileSync( curSource, targetFolder + file );